# Reading MSWord file at run time

Tags: python, r, ms-word

The structure of file is not important for me so from some previous [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491987/reading-and-scanning-ms-word-doc-files-in-r) as mentioned "converting them to plain text and importing them with readLines" ,i changed file type from ".doc/.docx" to ".txt" and end up with an error

```
file_list = list.files("D:/R/New",pattern="*.txt",full.names=F
obj_list <- lapply(file_list,readLines)
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(c("adityar.txt":
  incomplete final line found on 'adityar.txt'
```

I have tried to read with the help of corpus as well but didnt find good result ,here the second [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111207/read-an-msword-file-into-r) says about pdf and unix ,any better and fast approach, i am working on windows platform,any help.

Comment: You didn't just change the file name from `adityar.doc` to `adityar.txt` did you?

Comment: See http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/reading-in-MS-Word-files-td899087.html

Comment: @Aashu Are you open to python solution?

Comment: @agstudy Is it reading a file in python or conversion will be in python ?

Comment: @Andrie It is limited to word 2003,thanks for your help.

Comment: @agstudy python will also do,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using python ,  you can do this :

```
from docx import *
import json
document = opendocx("path_to_your_docx")
res = getdocumenttext(document)
```

You can save your script and call it from R using `system`