# How to convert doc to docx file using R code

Tags: r

I tried to read doc file using `readdoc()` but when doc file consist of tables, it will not able read it properly.

Therefore I want to convert doc file to docx file so that I can extract tables using `docxtractr` package availabe in R.

I want to convert `.doc` file to `.docx` file using R code.

Comment: I thought docx tables were just compressed XML files.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491987/reading-and-scanning-ms-word-doc-files-in-r

Comment: Run a `system2()` command to call the command-line outlined here https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/49770/batch-headless-conversion-from-doc-to-docx/